# Upper bound improper integral in terms of only the integrand

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ is a nonincreasing function with $f(0)=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$, and also suppose that $f$ is integrable, i.e. $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$. I am interested in bounding the quantity, for arbitrary $c>0$, $$\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$ in terms of ONLY the function $f$. For instance, it is my main goal to show that $\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = \mathcal{O}(f(c))$ for $c\to\infty$.

When $f(x)$ is rational-bounded (i.e., $f(x) \leq x^{-p}$ for $p > 1$) or exponential-bounded ($f(x) \leq e^{-ax}$ for $a>0$) it is easy to show these majorizations still hold for the quantity above. So I am hopeful that under the assumptions I have placed on the function $f$, the quantity above is majorized by $f(c)$ as $c\to\infty$ in general without having to refer to a "reference order of convergence" for $f$.

I have tried some of the obvious things, such as using the very weak bound $\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{c}$ on $[c,\infty)$ (this seems too weak and the result is in terms of the antiderivative of $f$) as well as integration by parts in both directions, a few $u$-substitutions, and trying to use Hölder's inequality to separate terms. Nothing has led anywhere obviously useful.

I have researched to see if anyone has asked/answered such a question before, and I did not find a question quite as general as this one. I did however notice that bounding the asymptotics of arbitrary integrals can be a daunting process, often involving tools such as complex analysis and long proofs. I would be open to the idea that what I am asking for is simply too strong.

It is also worth mentioning that there cannot be a bounded majorization that holds as $c\to 0$. It is straightforward to show via basic inequalities that if $f(b) \neq 0$ for any $b>0$, then for $c < b$, $$\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx \geq f(b)\ln(\tfrac{b}{c})$$ so the limit as $c\to 0$ is infinite.

I appreciate any insight! Thank you.

Comment: Your quantity $\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ depends only on $c$ and on $f$. If you want to find an upper bound that depends only on $f$, I understand that you are going to make it independent on $c$. But your example shows something different. I don't understand.

Comment: I assume OP wants a bound that's a simple closed expression in terms of $f$.

Comment: @Mateo I don't want to make the bound independent of $c$. Rather as Jair commented I want to find a "simple" function $F$ so that $\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx \leq F(c)$, where it is $F$ that only depends on $f$. Ideally, as $c\to\infty$ we would have $F \simeq f$ (perhaps their ratio tends to a finite constant).

Comment: Although much weaker than what OP wants, a trivial bound is $$\int_{c}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\leq\sqrt{\left(\int_{c}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\left(\int_{c}^{\infty}f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)}\leq \sqrt{\frac{f(c)}{c}\int_{c}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x},$$ which is obtained by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. But considering that you has already investigated Hölder's inequality, I guess you already know this...

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for this - Indeed, I suspected the use of Hölder's inequality would in general result in the antiderivative of $f$ showing up.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this in the future, it is possible to answer this question in the positive under a mild condition on $f$.

Namely, we require that $xf(x)$ is monotone (nonincreasing) for sufficiently large inputs. This prevents $f$ from being constant on an interval infinitely often, among other "difficult" functions. Suppose that $c$ is such that $xf(x)$ is nonincreasing on $[c,\infty)$ then we have that

$\begin{align*}
\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx &= \int_c^\infty xf(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}dx \leq cf(c)\int_c^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx = \frac{cf(c)}{c}=f(c).
\end{align*}$

Thus, $f(c)$ is an upper bound in this case.

If this condition fails to be true, we can make a similar argument. We define the following function:
$$d_f(c) := \min\{x\geq c:xf(x)\geq yf(y),\ \ \forall y\geq x\}$$
It remains to prove that $d_f$ is well-defined for the $f$ I have specified in my original post, but I am sure this is the case (namely, since $f$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$). Note that $d_f(c) \geq c$ by definition. Using this function, for any $c>0$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
\int_c^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx &= \int_c^{d_f(c)}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx + \int_{d_f(c)}^\infty xf(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
&\leq f(c)\int_c^{d_f(c)}\frac{1}{x}dx + d_f(c)f(d_f(c))\int_{d_f(c)}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
&= f(c)\ln\left(\tfrac{d_f(c)}{c}\right) + \frac{d_f(c)f(d_f(c))}{d_f(c)}\\
&= f(c)\ln\left(\tfrac{d_f(c)}{c}\right) + f(d_f(c))\\
&\leq f(c)\ln\left(\tfrac{d_f(c)}{c}\right) + f(c) = \left(1 + \ln\left(\tfrac{d_f(c)}{c}\right)\right)\cdot f(c).
\end{align*}$$
Above, we have primarily used the fact that $f$ is nonincreasing.

If one can use the definition of $f$ to bound the ratio of $d_f(c)$ to $c$, then this can lead to "near $f(c)$" bounds on the integral. It is not always possible to bound this ratio by a constant, but such examples seem to me to be pathological in nature. (For instance, a descending step function whose sequential step lengths are like $2^{2^x}$ with step heights decaying much faster for a finite integral. In this case, $\frac{d_f(c)}{c}$ has infinite limsup as $c$ grows large.)

It is worth noting that in the original condition ($xf(x)$ is nonincreasing for sufficiently large inputs), we have eventually that $d_f(c) = c$ for all $c$ sufficiently large, in which case we recover the original bound.